# K&R C book - exercise 3.3

Tags: c, strings, homework

I have an exercise in my ANSI C book:

> 3.3. Write a function `expand(s1,s2)` that expands shorthand notations like `a-z` in the string `s1` into the equivalent complete list `abc…xyz` in
>   `s2`. Allow for letters of either case and digits, and be prepared to
>   handle cases like `a-b-c` and `a-z0-9` and `-a-z`. Arrange that a leading or
>   trailing `-` is taken literally.

I have attempted to solve it and here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 100

void expand(char * s1, char * s2);

int main(void) {
    char s1[] = "a-b-c";
    char s2[MAXLEN];
    expand(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n", s2);
    return 0;
}

void expand(char * s1, char * s2) {
    char prev = '\0';
    char mid = '\0';
    char next = '\0';
    if (s1[0] == '-') {
        *s2 = *s1;
        s1++, s2++;
    }
    while (*s1 != '\0') {
        if (next == '\0' && mid == '-')
            *s2++ = mid;
        else if (mid == '-') {
            if (prev < next)
                for (char i = prev; i <= next; i++, s2++)
                    *s2 = i;
            else
                for (char i = prev; i >= next; i--, s2++)
                    *s2 = i;
        }
        prev = *s1;
        s1++;
        mid = *s1;
        if (*s1 != '\0')
            next = *(s1 + 1);
    }
    *s2 = *s1;
}
```

What do you think about this solution? Does it solve the exercise? Is it a good way to solve it?

Comment: Well, you are writing in ANSI C, not K&R C.  Your title reads “K&R C book”?

Comment: They are probably reffering to the second edition. K&R C is named after the C shown in "The C Programming Language". The second edition is modified to use ANSI C.

Comment: This is a terrible exercise. I don't understand the instructions at all. Does "be prepared to handle cases like a-b-c" mean the result would be `abbc`? or `abc`? And what does "Arrange that a leading or trailing -is taken literally." mean? Is it intended that when part of the string is not a range, that you simply copy it?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
```

We don't use any of the definitions of this header, so it can safely be omitted.

---

```
#define MAXLEN 100
```

Why 100?  More importantly, what happens when we reach this maximum length?  We probably need to add some code to stop producing output when it's reached.  The provided interface `expand(s1,s2)` doesn't allow us to tell the function how much space is available to write into `s2`, so that's probably out of scope for the exercise, but consider implementing `expand(s1,s2,max_len)` as a further exercise (and a good one, that will be useful in your future C coding).

---

What should the output be for `a-b-c`?  Your program produces `abbc`, but I don't know if that's expected.  At least add a comment to document your assumptions.  Other possible interpretations include `abc` and `ab-c`, so explain why you've chosen `abbc` for this input.

---

Another problematic test case: `--5`.

---

Use `const` for the input string.  If we also return the start of the output, we can use the function more naturally:

```
char *expand(const char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *const s2_start = s2;

    /*...*/

    return s2_start;
}

int main(void) {
    char s2[MAXLEN];
    puts(expand("--5", s2));
}
```

Note that I've used `puts()` as a simpler alternative to `sprintf("%s\n", )`.

---

Your indexing is odd and inconsistent.  I see `s1[0]` mixed in with `*s`, and `*(s1 + 1)` in place of the simpler `s1[1]`.  You can also make use of the *value* of increment expressions, like this:

```
if (*s1 == '-') {
    *s2++ = *s1++;
}
```

```
            char i = prev;
            if (prev < next)
                while (i <= next)
                    *s2++ = i++;
            else
                while (i >= next)
                    *s2++ = i--;
```

---

### Improved code

I've completely re-written, observing the above changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *expand(const char *s1, char *s2, int max_len) {
    char *const s2_start = s2;
    char *const s2_end = s2_start + max_len - 1;

    while (*s1 && s2 < s2_end) {
        if (*s1 == '-' && s2 != s2_start && s1[1]) {
            /* spotted hyphen not at beginning or end */
            char first = s1[-1];
            char last = *++s1;
            /* produce a range first..last,
               exclusive (we've already written first) */
            if (first == last) {
                ++s1;
            } else if (first < last) {
                /* ascending */
                for (char i = ++first;  i < last && s2 < s2_end;  ++i)
                    *s2++ = i;
            } else {
                /* descending */
                for (char i = --first;  i > last && s2 < s2_end;  --i)
                    *s2++ = i;
            }
        } else {
            /* copy to output */
            *s2++ = *s1++;
        }
    }
    *s2 = '\0';

    return s2_start;
}


#define MAXLEN 100
int main(void) {
    char s2[MAXLEN];
    puts(expand("a-z-a-z-a", s2, MAXLEN));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void expand(char * s1, char * s2);
```

Although the placement of `*` (`int * a` or `int* a` or `int *a`), I would stick to one and only one throughout a codebase. Later on you have `*s2 = *s1` so it's a good idea to use that style in the function signature as well.

Comment: But those are different cases. `int * a` is a parameter declaration, whereas `*s1 = *s2;` is an assignment. There's no reason you should expect them to be the same, in my opinion.

Comment: @user1118321 But they are not _'different cases'_. The C syntax of type declaration is explained as mimicking the expression context: `int *x` declares the `x` identifier to provide `int` value if used in the `*x` expression. OTOH surrounding the asterisk with spaces suggests the multiplication operator, which is misleading here.